# Box de diferentes altura se encaixarem igual Pinterest

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

Estou com um problema, não estou conseguindo deixar os blocos de diferentes alturas (height) mais ou menos igual ao pinterest, no meu caso são duas colunas respeitando a seguinte regra de responsivo `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6`, ou seja, duas colunas para desktop, e uma coluna para mobile e tablet.

Fiz um exemplo mais ou menos no https://jsfiddle.net/bwnmaq1s/ a ideia é `todos` os box respeitem a `margin-bottom` definida.

Aqui vai a imagem do meu problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Obs.:** Os box são incluídos dinamicamente, nunca sei o que vai vim depois e qual a altura dele, isso vai depender das ações dos usuários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erick o que consegui a respeito de sua dúvida é o chamado *Layout Grid Masonry* que é a quase a  mesma coisa do Waterfall da resposta do RBoschini, ele está bem aplicado [**aqui**](http://w3bits.com/labs/css-masonry/).

Inicialmente, ele é [feito com Jquery](http://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started), mas há uma maneira de ser feito com o CSS apenas.

A partir do seu exemplo fiz o seguinte, como você está usando a classe `col-md-6` do Bootstrap e esta equivale a um *breakpoint* de no mínimo **970px**, então criei um *Media querie* com essas definições:

```
@media (min-width: 970px) {
  .container {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-width: 50%;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-width: 50%;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

O que está dentro do `.container` é o que fará a mágica, o `column` do css. O problema é que aparentemente há um conflito deste com o Bootstrap, e o fato dele realizar um corte nas `divs`. O modo de resolver é aplicando um `overflow: auto`, um `height: 100%` no `.container` e ainda dentro do `querie` aplicar ao article um `break-inside: avoid-column` e um `-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid`. Ficaria assim:

```
@media (min-width: 970px) {
  .container {
    margin: 2em 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-width: 50%;
      -moz-column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-width: 50%;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-width: 50%;
      column-fill: auto;
  }
  article{
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/bwnmaq1s/50/)

[**JsFiddle FullScreen**](https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/bwnmaq1s/50/embedded/result/#Result)

**Mas isso é tudo muito relativo então teste aí no seu modelo e me avise qualquer coisa...**

Comment: Legal Sami muito boa resposta, usei esse Masonry e ta quase do jeito que eu quero, so tem uma coisa me intrigando aqui vou tentar resolve-la. Mais uma vez muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar column-width e column-gap da forma que usei nesse exemplo
[Exemplo pinterest](https://jsfiddle.net/4uxmftz1/1/)

Ou usar uma lib que faça isso para você, um exemplo é a lib waterfall
https://github.com/kudago/waterfall

Vejá qual caminho quer seguir, qualquer duvida, é só perguntar.

Comment: Tentei usar esse waterfall mas ele altera o width do meu box deixando pequeno e desconfigura meu layout, vou tentar fazer igual no seu exemplo.

Comment: Poutz tentei fazer seu exemplo aqui, deu mais ou menos certo ainda tem um erro ... olhe a imagem http://ap.imagensbrasil.org/image/pUQCS  ... o box om texto deveria ficar inteiro do lado direito e os box com imagem um em cima do outro.

Comment: Estou tentando usar agora o waterfall mas nao consigo deixar ele com duas colunas tipo ta funcionando mas os box ficam muito pequenos e nao ficam com duas colunas

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode criar um script para isso ou usar display table.
Pode também colocar um clearfix a cada 2, e eles ficaram mesma linha. 
Com jquery, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {<br>
        var a = $('.altura_eventos').height();<br>
        $('.imagem_evento_ita').css("min-height", a);<br>

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pega a altura da div dos dois eventos juntas e aplica ela para os dois eventos com min-height. 
Ele vai pegar sempre a altura da maior no caso.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. No meu caso os cards são adicionados dinamicamente nunca sei qual card vai vim e qual o tamanho dele iss ovai depende da ação do usuario, é como se fosse uma rede social!

Answer (score 0):

A cada 2 li's você coloca abre uma div e coloca a classe clearfix. 
Ela vai deixar as duas na mesma linha. 
Qualquer outro problema, você coloca min-height e ele irá funcionar. 
Por exemplo, um min-height nas Li's que você tem alí ou no próprio container onde pega a imagem amarela ou a escrita.